# Accidentally closed scanner in java and am now getting an IllegalStateException

Tags: java, io

While playing around with the scanner trying to write a method, I accidentally called `scanner.close()` and ran the program, not realizing this closes the input stream as well. Even though I took it out of my method, it seems that `IllegalStateExceptions` are being thrown due to the closed input stream (although I am using a readable object which is a field of my class as input). Is there a way I can reset the scanner so that it can take new inputs?

```
public void playGame() {
    String nextInput;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(this.reader);
    promptMove();
    while (!(this.model.isGameOver())) {
      if (scanner.hasNext()) {
        nextInput = scanner.next();
        if (nextInput.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {
          promptQuit();
          break;
        } else {
          addInputs(nextInput);
        }
        attemptControllerMove(input);
      }
      else {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Please enter valid moves.");
      }
    }
    if (this.model.isGameOver()) {
      promptGameOver();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Every time you run this code, an entirely new VM is started. You therefore cannot possibly 'close System.in for this process and all future invocations of it'. Perhaps you haven't recompiled or are otherwise still running the 'old' classfile.

Comment: I am not seeing where you call promptMove() inside the while loop which is, I assume, when something gets added to the stream the scanner is reading from. Is there another way you are getting the next input or should that be added?